# "В/рукопашную", - какой случай у меня в тексте?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

> И мы сейчас можем закатывать глаза от такого положения дел, но должны
>   не забывать, что война тогда велась в рукопашную.

Из бесед со Справкой:

[Вопрос № 251543](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=251543)

> Скажите, пожалуйста, в каких случаях "врукопашную" пишется слитно, а в
>   каких — раздельно. Например: "Солдаты пошли в[ ]рукопашную".
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Слитно пишется наречие *врукопашную* 'действуя руками или ручным
>   оружием (в борьбе, в бою с противником)': *драться* (как?)
>   *врукопашную, схватиться врукопашную, сойтись врукопашную, солдаты дрались врукопашную.*
>
> Раздельно пишется сочетание предлога *в* и существительного
>   *рукопашная* 'схватка, бой, осуществляемый без оружия или холодным оружием, штыками, прикладами': *солдаты пошли в рукопашную.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*И мы сейчас можем закатывать глаза от такого положения дел, но должны не забывать, что война тогда велась* (как?) *врукопашную.* Это наречие, так как отвечает на вопрос *как?* Вопрос во *что?* задать нельзя. Следовательно, пишем слитно.

Солдаты пошли (куда? во что?) в рукопашную (схватку). Здесь явно сочетание существительного с предлогом.

Comment: Я редко где видел, чтобы "в рукопашную" писалось раздельно.